# ¿Como llenar un arreglo unidimencional con valores de una columna? VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Me gustaria llenar un array unidimencional con valores de una columna de una hoja de excel dado que es muy problematico estar cambiando constantemente los valores insertados en el codigo, y creo que este problema se resolveria si en automatico toma los valores de una lista en una hoja de excel, esta seria mi opción si conocen alguna mejor pueden comentarmelo.

Actualmente tengo este codigo para almacenar los valores:

```
Dim strNames(1 To 10) As String
    strNames(1) = 10560
    strNames(2) = 10871
    strNames(3) = 10961
    strNames(4) = 11349
    strNames(5) = 11414

    strNames(6) = 11425
    strNames(7) = 11488
    strNames(8) = 614295
    strNames(9) = 856963
    strNames(10) = 870073
```

Y esto solo es un ejemplo dado que originalmente mi array tiene 56 elementos y pueden cambiar algunos de ellos por otros valores y tener que entrar al codigo y modificarlo es realmente problematico, ¿Existe una manera de hacer esto? No soy muy bueno con VBA y no conozco lo suficiente para buscar algo en concreto que me ayude, les agredeceria mucho su ayuda.